# Converting 5 bytes to an integer

Tags: java, python, int, type-conversion, byte

I have some weird data that's stored in 5 bytes and I need to be able to convert it to an int to be able to manipulate it easier. I have some Python code (that was provided to me) that does this already, but I need to be able to have a solution in Java. I think my problem is now Python and Java differ in the way they store bytes.

Python (98% sure this works correctly):

```
def bin5(b,k):
  """ Returns binary integer from bytes k,k+1,...,k+4 in b."""
  b0 = b[k  ]
  b1 = b[k+1]
  b2 = b[k+2]
  b3 = b[k+3]
  b4 = b[k+4]
  if b0<0: b0 += 256
  if b1<0: b1 += 256
  if b2<0: b2 += 256
  if b3<0: b3 += 256
  if b4<0: b4 += 256
  return b0*65536.0+b1*256.0+b2+b3/256.0+b4/65536.0
```

Java attempt:

```
  // Returns binary integer from bytes k,k+1,...,k+4 in b.
  private static int bin5(byte[] b, int k) {
    byte b0 = b[k];
    byte b1 = b[k + 1];
    byte b2 = b[k + 2];
    byte b3 = b[k + 3];
    byte b4 = b[k + 4];
    return (int)(b0 * 65536.0 + b1 * 256.0 + b2 + b3 / 256.0 + b4 / 65536.0);
  }
```

I'm certain the problem is in the last return statement of the Java code. Also, it will work for some byte arrays, but not for others. I can't find a reason for this behavior.

EDIT: Example: 
If the Python code reads the bytes: `0 11 -72 0 0` for b0 thru b5 respectfully, it will change the `-72` to `184` and then calculate the value `3000.0` based on the equation above. Based on the survey/data parameters, this value is correct.

My intuition says that the python code IS faulty for some values. One such value is when it reads a values `0 -127 -66 0 0` (b0 thru b5 respectfully) which turns into: `0 129 190 0 0` and then the value `33214` is output by the conversion. This is impossible based on the survey/data parameters. BUT there is a possibility that this could be a faulty data point.

EDIT 2: 
`0 13 9 0 0` should return 3337 (and does in the python code). However under Java, it returns 3593.

Comment: Isn't `byte` signed in Java? If so, how can you use `byte` to represent `b0` and so on since they range from 0 to 255. Also, you need to get rid of those `.0`'s -- the fractions could add up to an integer.

Comment: What problem are you seeing? also int's won't have decimals like how you are expecting. And bytes are signed and you are missing your sign conversion code that you have above.

Comment: This seems to be returning a float, not an int...

Comment: I think the .0's are there so integer division doesn't happen (not actually sure if this is an issue). I'm not familiar enough with bytes and how they represent numbers. The return then gets cast as an int, so I don't think fge is on the right track.

EDIT: Daniel: Let's say the data is suppose to read 3000 from the 5 bytes, in some cases it will read 3000. However, depending on the bytes, if it's suppose to read something like 3514, it will instead read 3820. A value that is +256 off.

Comment: Where is it cast as an int? Certainly not in the python code you showed so far

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. The python code gets used in a different way. It's fine to have the python code return a float. Really all it does is tack on a .0 to the value returned by the python code.

Comment: Look at my edited answer (one difference only; an off-by-one error), it works with all your examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
private static double bin5(byte[] b, int k) {
    int b0 = b[k] & 0xFF;     // treat as unsigned byte
    int b1 = b[k + 1] & 0xFF;
    int b2 = b[k + 2] & 0xFF;
    int b3 = b[k + 3] & 0xFF;
    int b4 = b[k + 4] & 0xFF;
    return (b0 * 65536 + b1 * 256 + b2 + b3 / 256.0 + b4 / 65536.0);
}
```

As powers of 2 can be represented exactly with `double` you won't get any rounding error.

Comment: That's gorgeous. Works great. Thank you. Do you happen to have any insight on if the python code is faulty for some `byte[]`s (as in the second paragraph of my first edit)?

Comment: @voltnor The python looks ok to my uneducated eyes (I don't know python)  The `if(b<0) b+=256` seems clunky and perhaps it supports masking like C/Java.

Comment: I'll look into it. The Java code produces the same large values, so maybe it is just a bad data point. Unfortunately I don't have a way of telling right now. Shucks.

Answer (score 0):

This code is strange; it does not return an integer at all but a float...

Anyway, the Java equivalent of the python code is something like this (note: NO bounds checking is done *at all*):

```
private static double bin5(final byte[] b, final int k)
{
    final ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);
    buf.position(3);
    buf.put(b, k, 5);
    buf.rewind();
    final long l = buf.getLong();
    return (double) l / 65536.0;
}
```

EDIT: if the last two elements of the byte array at offset `k` are always 0 (which it looks like they are) then you can replace from `buf.rewind()` onwards with:

```
buf.position(2);
return (double) buf.getInt();
```

Comment: The data has a very specific format so the bounds aren't an issue. And returning a double?

Comment: Well, look at the original python code: it _does_ return a float, not an int (dividing a byte by 256.0 gives a float)

Comment: Also, this doesn't work. If the byte array is representing the value 3000, it returns 768000.0. Thank you though!

Comment: Well then, edit the question with an example byte array and how you extract 3000 out of it ;)

Comment: All edited in with two examples. I'm not certain what the second should be outputting, but it should be in the 3000s.

Comment: Which byte order are you expecting?

Comment: Heh, off-by-one error... Now it works (the .position() argument was wrong)